# Scheme - binary tree iteration recursion appends () as an empty Node instead of nothing

Tags: recursion, append, scheme

I'm trying to write a simple code which returns a list of the tree nodes values in a "pre-order" way.

```
(define pre-iter  (lambda (tree)
(if (not (pair? tree))
    (list tree)
    (append (list (car tree)) (pre-iter (cadr tree)) (pre-iter (caddr tree)))
)))
```

I can't find out why the following happens:

```
  (iter-tree (quote (F (B A (D C E)) (G () (I H ())))) pre-iter): expected '(F B A D C E G I H), got '(F B A D C E G () I H ())
```

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to handle an extra case when a subtree is null. Try this:

```
(define pre-iter
  (lambda (tree)
    (cond ((null? tree) '())
          ((not (pair? tree)) (list tree))
          (else
           (append (list (car tree))
                   (pre-iter (cadr  tree))
                   (pre-iter (caddr tree)))))))
```

It works as requested:

```
(pre-iter '(F (B A (D C E)) (G () (I H ()))))
=> '(F B A D C E G I H)
```

Comment: Thanks Oscar, I ended up using the operator "flatten" which removes brackets from lists